# It is correct for hide or unhide a control by VBA in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet named "MainSheet" in a Workbook in Excel 2010.

this sheet included an activeX control named "OptionButton1". when the cell's value of "C18" is "2" then this control should be hide.

I wrote below code but does not work.

► a more question: can I have three activeX (Radio Button) related to one cell with three different value like radio button in form control?

Any advice is appreciated. :)

```
Sub MS_Method()

If Range("C18").Value = 2 Then

    ActiveSheet.MainSheet("OptionButton1").Visible = False

ElseIf Range("C18").Value = 1 Then

    ActiveSheet.MainSheet("OptionButton1").Visible = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: what is `ActiveSheet.MainSheet` ? is `MainSheet` defined and set as a Wroksheet ?

Comment: I just renamed the default "Sheet1" name to "MainSheet" for mentioned Worksheet in this Workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your ActiveX `OptionButton` is Named "OptionButton1", the code below (tested) will work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MS_Method()

Dim Sht                 As Worksheet

' modify "MainSheet" to your sheet name (where you have your OptionButton)
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainSheet")

If Range("C18").Value = 2 Then
    Sht.OLEObjects("OptionButton1").Visible = False
ElseIf Range("C18").Value = 1 Then
    Sht.OLEObjects("OptionButton1").Visible = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: a more question: can I have three activeX (Radio Button) related to one cell with three different value (1 or 2 or 3) like radio button in form control?

Comment: @Kasra not sure about it, never tried it. You can post a new question with your updated code. and please mark this as Answer

Comment: Thank you again ... how can I set as answer?

Comment: @Kasra you put a "V" next to me answer (on the top left side of my answer post)

Comment: I clicked on the " ^ " symbol on top-left your answer. alse I set "Active" tag on the top of your answer...

is it true my friend?